# Lorenz Curve for a Normal Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

The Lorenz Curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve) is a visual representation of the equality of income distribution across a population. It plots the cumulative fraction of total income versus the bottom fraction of population that earns it, so both the domain (fraction of population) and range (fraction of total income) extend from 0 to 1. I'd like to generate the Lorenz curve for various income distributions (just for brain-limbering), starting with normal.

From the linked article, for a distribution with PDF *f(x)*, CDF *F(x)*
, and mean $\mu $, the associated Lorenz Curve is 
$$L\left( {F\left( x \right)} \right) = {1 \over \mu }\int\limits_{ - \infty }^x {t\;f\left( t \right)dt} $$

For the normal distribution, $f\left( x \right) = \phi \left( x \right)$, $F\left( x \right) = \Phi \left( x \right)$, and therefore

$$L\left( {\Phi \left( x \right)} \right) = {1 \over \mu }\int\limits_{ - \infty }^x {t\;\phi \left( t \right)dt} $$

Refreshing an ancient memory of the Product Rule for integration,

$$\int {u\;dv}  = uv - \int {v\;du} $$

So let $u = t$ and ${dv = \phi \left( t \right)dt}$; then $du=dt$ and ${v = \Phi \left( t \right)}$. Then

$$L\left( {\Phi \left( x \right)} \right) = {1 \over \mu }\left( {\left. {t\;\Phi \left( t \right)} \right|_{ - \infty }^x - \int\limits_{ - \infty }^x {\Phi \left( t \right)dt} } \right) = {1 \over \mu }\left( {t\;\Phi \left( x \right) - \int\limits_{ - \infty }^x {\Phi \left( t \right)dt} } \right)$$

Assuming that's correct so far, I've run out of steam. Is there a common function to evaluate that definite integral on the right?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: look up Truncated normal distribution and its mean

Comment: It's $\mu  + {{\phi \left( \alpha  \right) - \phi \left( \beta  \right)} \over {\Phi \left( \beta  \right) - \Phi \left( \alpha  \right)}}\sigma $. Not sure where that's supposed to point me.

Comment: ur original rhs is that truncated at x

Comment: I apologize for obviously missing something obvious. So I can calculate the mean at x of the right-truncated distribution as $\mu ' = \mu  - {{\phi \left( x \right)} \over {\Phi \left( x \right)}}\sigma $. How does that help evaluate the integral at that point?

Answer (score 1):

actually for normal distribution you can do the integration directly. this is just another way.

$\alpha=\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}=-\infty, \beta=\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

$\mu'\equiv \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{x}tf(t)dt}{\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt}=\mu+\frac{\phi(\alpha)-\phi(\beta)}{\Phi(\beta)-\Phi(\alpha)}\sigma=\mu-\frac{\phi(\beta)}{\Phi(\beta)}\sigma$

$L(F(x))=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{x}tf(t)dt=\frac{\mu'\Phi(\beta)}{\mu}=\Phi(\beta)-\frac{\phi(\beta)}{\mu}\sigma$

The direct way:

$L(F(x))=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{x}tf(t)dt=\frac{1}{\mu}(\mu\Phi(\beta)+\int_{-\infty}^{x}(t-\mu)f(t)dt)$

$=\Phi(\beta)+\frac{1}{\mu\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}(t-\mu)\cdot e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\cdot dt$

$=\Phi(\beta)+\frac{\sigma}{\mu\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{t-\mu}{\sigma}\cdot e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\cdot d{\frac{t-\mu}{\sigma}}$

$=\Phi(\beta)-\frac{\sigma}{\mu\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\beta}d{e^{-\frac{t.'^2}{2}}}$

$=\Phi(\beta)-\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\beta^2}{2}}$

$=\Phi(\beta)-\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\phi(\beta)$

Comment: Sorry to be a dunce. In the top equation, *x*, $ \mu $, and $\sigma\ $ are all in dollars, and $ \beta $ is the Z score of salary *x*. In the bottom equation, *x* is the population fraction [0,1). I can't connect the dots. Also, might you have a sign wrong?

Comment: Still struggling. In $\eqalign{
  & L\left( {F\left( x \right)} \right) = \Phi \left( \beta  \right) - {{\phi \left( \beta  \right)} \over \mu }\sigma   \cr }$, and taking $x = 50000$, $\mu  = 50000$, and $\sigma  = 20000$, what is $L\left( {0.5} \right)$, the fraction of total income earned by the bottom half of the population?